# Super slow image loading on a friend's website

Tags: wordpress, performance, web

My friend hired a guy to build her company's website, but the developer has since stopped responding to her attempts to contact him. The site performance is pretty poor, especially because it's a graphic design company. The images *should* be the most prominent and accessible elements on the page, but they load horribly slowly.

I looked at the page source but I'm a total novice with webdev and this site was developed using WordPress, I think. I'm just trying to help out my friend, so I'm wondering if anyone has ideas why the images might be so slow to load and what I should look into as far as fixing them. Could it be as simple as image size or format? Or how they're loaded? Or where they're loaded *from*?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Here's the website URL: http://studiosaltdesigns.com/

Comment: The image is 2 megabytes, what do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

There are more issues at play here than just large images loading slowly.

Testing load speed via http://tools.pingdom.com I can see there are over 10 `.css` files loading on the homepage and over 20 `.js` files (many of which aren't [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming))).

As the prvious answers suggest, you should think about optimising your images (reduce file size) but also try to minify and reduce the number of resources being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The way the site is built is it hides the images until they've loaded, with that being said your main first image is huge resolution of (3128x1505) the image should be a lot smaller around (1280x600) for full screen images and compressed greatly as that images size is 2mb when the most it should be is around 300-500kb. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons for slow image loads.

Usually the most common I see are images are not optimized for the web. This meaning the picture resolution is more than 72. 72 being the web standard. Another reason may be very large images. Try to make the images smaller sizes and see what happens

I looked into the page source to try and get the image size. This site has many links and javascript links in the head of the page. Most of the time javascript links should be at the bottom of the body.

Look into optimizing the images. I use ImageOpt for mac. Here is the download link. It is free.

http://imageoptim.en.softonic.com/mac

Hope this helps.